# How to parse outlook email using spring

Tags: java, spring, outlook

I have a use case where i need to read the content of the mail in outlook inbox and convert it into xml and send it to diffrent system.Is there any library which can help me in parsing the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook is the client for the email server.(May be exchange server).
You actually need to connect to the server to read the email. 
If you know the server, you can find a API for it.

Checkout this URL if you are trying to access the exchange server:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi

Comment: Thanks mayuran.I enabled the imap access to the Exchange server and able to connect through it.